# What is the term describing someone who has interest in only a narrow field, and nothing else?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

There are some people who have interests in only some narrow field, and are not interested in anything else:

- physicians who heal only ears, and for whom the stomach doesn't matter
- clerks who know all the fiscal laws by heart, but ignore anything that isn't written there
- fanatics who care only what the scriptures say
- housewives interested only in cooking and soap operas
- geeks who care only for computer games and comics
- crazy scientists that know everything about chemistry but don't know who Columbus was and have probably never heard of America

What do I call someone who has such narrow-field interests and/or knowledge?

Comment: Hmm. The list seems to imply you want a word with a somewhat pejorative connotation. I have no problem with specialists (physicians) who concentrate on a focused area. We need them. We can't be specialists in everything.  In answer, I'd say single-minded.

Comment: Łukasz 웃 L ツ, you should edit the *How* in your last line and replace it with a *What*.

Comment: Oh, and Sherlock Holmes. Didn't know about the solar system (and other fundamentals) and didn't care.

Comment: Narrow-minded perhaps?

Comment: Single-minded actually has a positive connotation, Susan. A single-minded person is focused, determined, driven by a zeal (for a single goal) unthinkable to most of us. Narrow-minded, close-minded ,limited, etc. These are more appropriate words.

Comment: @D. M. Davidson: I do not agree. Narrow-minded comes to mind because the questions indicates the word "narrow" but narrow-minded has negative connotations that is beyond the definition in the question.

Comment: Perhaps related: http://matt.might.net/articles/phd-school-in-pictures/

Comment: Sounds like you are mixing several concepts together, and no one word will suffice: _physicians who heal only ears..._ is definitely called a "specialist", but that's not the appropriate term for _fanatics who care only what the scriptures say_ or _housewives interested only in cooking and soap operas_

Comment: @ermanen: You're quite right-in fact all the words I listed as appropriate are not exactly applicable to this situation, where the physician has 'specialized'.

Comment: I've seen _one-dimensional_ used for such people.

Answer (score 30):

Consider [monomaniac](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/monomaniac): someone with "an inordinate or obsessive zeal for or interest in a single thing, idea, subject, or the like"

Answer (score 28):

Consider [**specialist**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/specialist)

> A person who concentrates primarily on a particular subject or activity; a person highly skilled in a specific and restricted field.

Comment: If "specialist" is good at conveying narrow... "sub-specialist" must be even better, right? :)  +1

Comment: Being specialist doesn't include being interested in other domains, specialist can be omniscient as well. I'm asking about someone, who isn't interested in anything from other domains.

Answer (score 27):

Consider [**single-minded**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/single-minded)

> having only one purpose, goal, or interest : focused on one thing

Comment: Single-minded carries connotations that it is a temporary condition that will terminate when a goal is reached, whereas the asker used examples with permanence of interest.

Comment: @Aaron Hall: How can you say that it is temporary? It can be applied to both permanent and temporary situations.

Comment: Can you give such an example of unmodified usage?

Answer (score 15):

Consider **[parochial](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/parochial)**

> restricted to a small area or scope; narrow; limited; provincial: *a parochial outlook*

A similar recent term is **[laser focused](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=laser%20focus)**

> Intensely paying attention to a single object, concept, person, or activity to the exclusion of everything else.

Comment: Don't forget about "razor-focused," the likely ancestor of "laser-focused"

Comment: @Adrian Hmmmm.  A laser *could* be focused, but I would be quite surprised if you could "focus" any line.

Answer (score 11):

**"One-track mind"**, is used for people that have a singular interest that prevails over all other topics and outside influences.  As [defined](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/one-track-mind) by the MacMillan Dictionary:

> someone who has a one-track mind thinks about one particular thing all
>   the time

Answer (score 11):

**Tunnel Vision** describes the inability to see anything outside of your own narrow point of view.

Per the [definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tunnel%20vision) it is a tendency to think about only one thing and ignore everything else.

I believe it fits your idea.

Answer (score 9):

German has the word ***Fachidiot*** (literally: *profession idiot* or *subject idiot)* for this and [it has been prominently suggested](http://blogs.telegraph.co.uk/news/kateconnolly/3637231/Are_you_a_Fachidiot/) that English loans this word.

Comment: Fachidiot does not appear in the OED or Merriam Webster. I had not met the word in English before. I would avoid it.

Answer (score 5):

"Blinkered":

> [Having or showing a narrow or limited outlook:
>   '*a blinkered attitude*'](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/blinkered?q=blinkered)
>
> [limited in scope or understanding :  narrow-minded](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blinkered)

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be asking for the corollary to "polymath."  It's not a dictionary word, but I would consider using "monomath."

Answer (score 2):

Metaphorically, a [hedgehog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hedgehog_and_the_Fox).

> Berlin ... divide[s] writers and thinkers into two categories:
>   hedgehogs, who view the world through the lens of a single defining
>   idea ... and foxes who draw on a wide variety of experiences and for
>   whom the world cannot be boiled down to a single idea.

Answer (score 2):

How about a "wonk":

wonk noun \ˈwäŋk, ˈwȯŋk\
: a person who knows a lot about the details of a particular field (such as politics) and often talks a lot about that subject

Answer (score 2):

***Geek***

Although the asker said:

> - geeks who care only for computer games and comics

the term *geek* can apply to anyone who is obsessed with any field of interest, and is more useful in a casual situation where it imparts moderate and positive connotations, as opposed to my other favorite already given here, the more severe and clinical *monomaniac*.

Comment: This is a great answer!

Comment: This does not address the "but knows nothing in other areas."

Answer (score 1):

Couple words came to mind:

-Insular

> Circumscribed and detached in outlook and experience

-Provincial

> a person of local or restricted interests or outlook

Answer (score 1):

More words that come to mind:

[preoccupation](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/preoccupation?s=t)

> something that holds the attention or preoccupies the mind

[fixation](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fixation)

> a preoccupation with one subject, issue, etc.;

Comment: This does not address the question which asks for a noun for a person...

Answer (score 1):

This person is called a Subject Matter Expert (SME):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject-matter_expert

This is professional term - unlike some of the other answers. And is generally well understood in the business/professional world.

Comment: SME doesn't have the connotation of "and ... not interested in anything else".

Answer (score 1):

The term is "Specialist" when discussing professionals.

The term is "Myopic" when discussing people who see the world through only one narrow lens...

Comment: This does not address the question.

Answer (score 1):

**Idiot savant** is barely politically correct, carries implications of abnormal neurology, and is probably more extreme than what you're trying to say. Other than that, it matches pretty well:

> Quick definitions from WordNet: *idiot savant*
>
> ▸ noun:  person who is mentally retarded in general but who displays
>   remarkable aptitude in some limited field (usually involving memory)

Cf. *[savant](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/savant)*.

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for a term with a negative connotation as suggested by a previous comment?

Maybe **pedantic** is what you're looking for.  Someone who is overly concerned with minor details is considered *pedantic*.

```
pedantic
adj 1: marked by a narrow focus on or display of learning
       especially its trivial aspects [syn: academic,
       donnish, pedantic]
```

Answer (score -1):

We can call him as

### Nerd

Definition:

```
a single-minded expert in a particular technical field.
```

Check this [google dictionary](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=define%20nerd&oq=define%20nerd&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2037j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: This does not address the "but knows nothing in other areas."