# A word that means "a focused person"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I am looking for a word which sums up the idea of "a focused person."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relevant terms suggested in the questions [What is the term describing someone who has interest in only a narrow field, and nothing else?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/155385) and  [Single word for people who are like “a frog in the well”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/51451) include *confined, insular, one-track mind, monomath, limited, narrow,  single-minded, narrow-minded, razor-focused, laser-focused, together, small-minded, blinkered,  monomaniac, fixated, obsessed, specialist, Subject Matter Expert, hedgehog, bulldog, locked-in, tunnel vision, idée fixe, myopic, solipsist, navel-gazer, introverted*, et al.