# Squints (AE)- similar to the German word ‚Fachidiot‘?

Tags: meaning-in-context, translation

Is the word ‚squints‘ similar to the German word ‚Fachidiot‘?

It‘s often used from Agent Booth (Series Bones) when he speaks about the scientists.

Comment: This is not at all a common term in the US.  And i have no idea what the German term means.

Comment: Fachidiot translates directly as "professional idiots" so it's a distainful term.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there really no English equivalent to German's “Fachidiot”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/327748/is-there-really-no-english-equivalent-to-germans-fachidiot)

Comment: On the rare occasion I've seen "squints" in this sense, I've taken it to mean, roughly, "nerds" -- these are the guys that squint at microscopes, wordy text, or complicated computer screens.

Comment: My working assumption for the usage in "Bones" was that the show-runners wanted an unfamiliar term for Booth to use, so the level of insult (intended or received) remained vague.